# changing the appearance of a text file

Tags: awk

I have a text file as follows.

```
>1KKW
IYLCAVLLIL
>1WY6
GSLLILKR
>1Z23
LTLQQVINLAFQ
>1ZQS

>2B25
AV
>2L3Z
LLIL
>2OPT

>3AZO
SFNVAKR
```

I would like to arrange the above file as shown below. How can I do this with awk? Your help would be appreciated!

Desired output

```
1KKW     IYLCAVLLIL
1WY6     GSLLILKR
1Z23     LTLQQVINLAFQ
1ZQS     no residues
2B25     AV
2L3Z     LLIL
2OPT     no residues
3AZO     SFNVAKR
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an  `awk`

```
awk 'NF {$2="\t"($2==""?"no residues":$2)} NF' RS=\> file
1KKW    IYLCAVLLIL
1WY6    GSLLILKR
1Z23    LTLQQVINLAFQ
1ZQS    no residues
2B25    AV
2L3Z    LLIL
2OPT    no residues
3AZO    SFNVAKR
```

Here I do use `>` as a record selector, since it should give the start of the line 
Then next data is printed as `$2`, if there are no data in `$2` use `"no residues"`

Comment: Thanks, even shorten more.

Comment: or `awk 'NF{$2=$2?"\t"$2:"\tno residues"}NF' RS=\> file` `:P`

Comment: or `sed 'N;s/>//;s/\n/\t/;s/\t$/&no residues/' file`

Comment: You can move the "\t" to the common area at the front of the assignment instead of duplicating it, it will fail with a syntax error in some awks due to the non-parenthesised ternary expression, and it will incorrectly print "no residues" if $2 contains a string that evaluates to numeric zero. It should be written as: `awk 'NF {$2="\t"($2==""?"no residues":$2)} NF' RS=\> file` but IMHO it'd be clearer still as `awk 'NR>1{$2="\t"($2==""?"no residues":$2);print}' RS=\> file`.

Comment: @EdMorton I did see that solution too, but taking out the `\t` did not save any byte, since I then needed to add `()`.  But it looks cleaner, so I change it.

Comment: @Jotne you need to add the `()` anyway to avoid syntax errors with some awks. Always parenthesize ternary expressions.

Comment: @Jotne Yeah, I don't know what the history is or standards say but in awk on OSX, for example, you can use a non-parenthesised ternary expression in some situations but not in others. For example, this is fine: `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%s\n", NR%3?0:$1 }'` and this is fine: `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%s\n", (NR==3?0:$1) }'` but this is a syntax error: `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%s\n", NR==3?0:$1 }'`. Rather than worry about whether or not it's going to fail without parens, I think it's best to just always parenthesize it.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point and explanation.  I do like the solution to be portable, so its important to remember all this tweaks and tricks.

Comment: Not fair you didn't have any Enlightened nor Nice Answer badges yet. +1 for all good work on awk tag so far!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", ( sub(/^>/,"") ? $0"\t" : (NF?$0:"no residues")ORS )}' file
1KKW    IYLCAVLLIL
1WY6    GSLLILKR
1Z23    LTLQQVINLAFQ
1ZQS    no residues
2B25    AV
2L3Z    LLIL
2OPT    no residues
3AZO    SFNVAKR
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a multi-line `sed` solution ...

Command:

```
sed -e '{
N
s/\n/\t/
s/>//g
s/\t$/\tno residues/g
}' text.txt
```

Results:

```
1KKW    IYLCAVLLIL
1WY6    GSLLILKR
1Z23    LTLQQVINLAFQ
1ZQS    no residues
2B25    AV
2L3Z    LLIL
2OPT    no residues
3AZO    SFNVAKR
```

Comment: Yes, I know the question asked for an awk solution.  Since there were two awk solutions already provided, I threw in a sed solution for the heck of it.  Was it really necessary to down vote it?

Comment: You have just taken my golfed solution, made it worse and posted it as your own.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen your golfed solution.  I'm sure you're a wonderful sed-ist, but that line was created independently using the sed man pages and the information already in my head.  Yes, it's not perfect, since it performs 3 passes at the line, but I never said it was perfect.